# decrease z-index of fullcalendar today's date

Tags: css, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar and during some ajax request I am adding overlay for processing request exactly like http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.9.2/spinners_usage.html (as I am using inspina theme). However, the color of `fc-today` or `fc-state-highlight` is always remaining on top of this overlay. I have tried increasing th z-index of class to `999999`. On top of that, I have also tried by making z-index of `fc-today` and `fc-state-highlight` to 1. But, still the fc-today color is on top of that overlay.

[image: screenshot]

Update:

To give some idea about my problem: [Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/prying/pen/JQLomp)

Comment: You need to provide a proper [mre], instead of just vaguely telling us what you did and what didn’t work …

Comment: @04FS I have updated question with codepen link please have a look.

Comment: Looks like this isn’t even primarily a z-index issue. Your “spinner” element itself is only 50px wide and 30px high - so it doesn’t matter if you put that at the very top of everything on the z-axis, it would still not cover the today column …

Comment: 04FS is right, the area covered by the spinner element, which has the z-index, doesn't go over the top of the "today" column at all. Nor does it have a background colour to obscure anything under it. So I'm not clear why you expected this to work.

Comment: So, how can I make that look weird? Does that mean, i cannot place overlay over the todays column?

Comment: Of course you can, if you make it big enough

Comment: @ADyson Sorry, there a typo on my previous comment. All I want is to get rid of that weird look that means I want to cover that `today's column` with the background color of that overlay. Does that make sense? How can I do this?

Comment: By a). making the overlay bigger, and b) giving it a background colour to start with - right now it doesn't have one. We must have said this, in different ways, 4 times now. Have you tried it yet? Do you understand how to make it bigger? Or is that the problem?

Comment: @ADyson No, I couldn't get it as I'm quite new to this. Could you show some codepen / jsfiddle link instead?

Comment: I think you'd got the CSS over-complicated with use of `:after` and so on, it's not necessary. Also you had the calendar within the overlay which made no sense - the overlay is supposed to be over the top of it, so it has to be a separate part of the markup, and also the overlay needs to have a fixed position, and have its own background colour. This is probably closer to what you want: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/RzJLWB